# How do I make the iPhone status bar transparent in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I am looking to hide the navigation and status bar to make it transparent. I have an image right below that I want to take up the entire space. So far, I got to hide the navigation bar but the status bar is still white- this is in the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Also, how can I re add the back button to the the navigation bar?

Thanks!

Screen shot of my current iPhone simulator:

[image]

[image: Screen shot after add Mohy Gh's code]

Edited after Mohy Gh's Code:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 3:** for whole app:

do this in your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method instead of hiding the navigation bar:

```
// Sets navigationBar's background to a blank/empty image       
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),
                                                for: .default)

// Sets shadow (line below the bar) to a blank image
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
```

**EDIT :** to hide `navigationBar` for one specific view controller in your View controller do like this :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

    navigationBar?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationBar?.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationBar?.isTranslucent = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

    navigationBar?.shadowImage = nil
    navigationBar?.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    navigationBar?.isTranslucent = false
}
```

After making the `navigationBar` transparent, you need to set your `imageView` 's top constraint to `topLayoutGuid` = `0`

if you you want to also hide `statusBar` for one `viewController` also put this in your desired viewController:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: what if I just wanted to hide it for only one specific view controller and not all of them?

Comment: @Sam I edited my post :) if it worked please select it as the right answer :)

Comment: It's getting there but I actually don't want to hide the status bar! I just want it so that my picture takes up the entire space from the status bar and down. So that I can still see the status bar and it's information is just above the picture. So the navigation bar is disappeared but the status bar is transparent. Closer to my first screenshot

Comment: so just ignore overriding the `prefersStatusBarHidden` , you can achive what you want by just making `navigationBar` transparent, and set your `imageView` 's top constraint to `topLayoutGuid` :S

Comment: Oh okay- I think I got it to work. Would I be able to still add a back button on the photo then? like the original back button from the navigation bar?

Comment: yes because if you don't hide navigation bar you can still access it components, try adding tint color like `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor  = ...`
and check if you can see back button or not :)

Comment: Add ViewController base status bar to no in info plist file